# Battery charging however phone not turning on, after being in a puddle

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery, screen

A while ago I dropped my Samsung Galaxy S in a puddle, the phone came apart (the battery & back cover came off). I quickly wiped the parts and put them in my pocket (without turning it on), when I got home I opened it up, wiped the parts and left it in the window sill for it to dry.

About 3 days later I checked to see if everything was working but only the Samsung logo came up at the start, then it just froze. The next morning I tried turning it on to see if it worked and it wouldn't start, completely. When I try to charge it, it doesn't show a battery sign and it won't load up into recovery or download mode.

Since I had downloaded a custom ROM I'd hoped plugging a USB jig in would get it in download mode so I could redownload the original ROM – however it didn't do anything.

I know the battery is charging as I checked to see if the battery was working by connecting it to a led, it didn't start so I knew the battery was dead; I left the phone plugged in and after about 10 mins I checked to see if it would work so I connected an LED light and it worked.

The battery is definitely charging so the problem isn't the battery, could it be the screen? Or something wrong with the circuit? Whenever I touch my phone screen, it does seem to be moist and wet.

Any help appreciated, I'd like not to get a new phone so if there is any chance of recovering it please let me know.

Comment: Most likely it is a hardware problem. Take it to a local mobile service center for confirmation.

Comment: would it be possible to fix it?
Also is there a way to check for short circuiting?

Comment: If the screen is still moist, then there's probably moisture trapped in the phone despite sitting on a window sill for three days. Try placing your phone in a small airtight container full of rice for a couple of days, with the back cover off and the battery removed.

Comment: will do :), il let you know how it goes